# Regex to find a word which ins n delimiters ahead of a matching string

Tags: regex

I need to get a specific word from a long string. The string consists of a large number of arrays `[…]`

The word I’m looking for is the number from the second element of the array (`83` in the sample). It can be 1,2 or 3 digit number that is always preceded by a „w“ and always followed by `„.gc“`

The word I can match is `„Go“` from the 4th element of the array within the dictionary value of „operations“. It’s the only occurrence of that word (including the quotes). And what’s important: there’s always 10 commas between `„Go“` and `„w83.gc“`

Any help is appreciated! I am using regex in the iOS shortcuts app.

```
[…]
,["call","w83.gc","draw",
 {"operations":
[["beginPath"],["rect",0,0,245,80],
["fill"],["fillText",
"Go",
false,
true,
true,
123,
24],
["drawImage",
"rwt-resources/generated/e4f6c8af.png",0,0,32,32,24,24,32,32]]}]
[…],…
```

**EDIT:**

The pattern “w”Number”.gc” occurs a lot in the stream. So I cannot use it to match. I can only use the `“Go”` to match

Comment: Your question is not very clear...not sure if you are looking for this.

w(\d+).gc

1st group will return you the number

Comment: Sorry I was not clear indeed. The pattern ‚w….gc‘ occurs  a lot in the entire string. So I cannot use the w and the gc to match. I can only use “Go” to match

Comment: this regex will work for all. It will match all the occurrence of 'w….gc' pattern

Comment: Yes. That is the problem. It will return all the occurrences. But I only need this one occurrence that is followed by a “Go” ten commas later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following regex. Group 1 will have the number.

```
w(\d+).gc(.*?,){10}\"Go\"
```

For Ref: https://regexr.com/5s4qf

Note: This will only work if the text is in a single line (without line breaks)

Comment: It’s working! However, the string seems to be too long to be matched with a regular expression in a shortcut. There’s a timeout for each action. But this has nothing to do with the fact that your answer does exactly what I needed! Thank you!